# ExponentAV: Player is accessed on the wrong thread

Tags: react-native, audio, expo, expo-av

I am noticing some issues with Expo-AV after updating to SDK 45. I am using react-native with an expo managed project.

I am receiving this error when trying to pause the sound using `sound.pauseAsync()` :

[Unhandled promise rejection: Error: Encountered an exception while calling native method: Exception occurred while executing exported method setAudioMode on module ExponentAV: Player is accessed on the wrong thread. See https://exoplayer.dev/issues/player-accessed-on-wrong-thread]

Here is my setAudio code:

```
await Audio.setAudioModeAsync({
            staysActiveInBackground: true,
            //interruptionModeAndroid: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX,
            shouldDuckAndroid: false,
            playThroughEarpieceAndroid: false,
            allowsRecordingIOS: false,
            //interruptionModeIOS: Audio.INTERRUPTION_MODE_IOS_DO_NOT_MIX,
            playsInSilentModeIOS: true,
            
          });
```

InterruptionModes are commented out because of another error I was receiving:

Property 'INTERRUPTION_MODE_ANDROID_DO_NOT_MIX' does not exist on type 'typeof import("/Users/rjm/blip-dev/node_modules/expo-av/build/Audio")

does anyone know what might be causing this or how I can fix it?

Comment: put your code in try{}catch(){} block if you don't want to worry about the error.

Answer (score 0):

i have the same error and i solved it by put the object of the audio class out of the component function [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7T8lL.png)

and if your object in a constructor of class you can Put the object of this class out of the component function [look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LIhZJ.png) - [and here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6YLd0.png) don't use any hook in this constructor this may cause error